# grunt-connect middleware for testing file uploads

Tags: gruntjs

How can I use grunt-connect with livereload to test uploading files to a server?

I'm using Yeoman and angular-seed for my project. One of the requirements is the ability to upload files to the server. Rather than setting up some external server for the project, I'd like to be able to keep everything contained in my current setup.

This solution adds middleware directly into Gruntfile.js for grunt-connect.

First it loads [connect bodyParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html) which makes it easier to parse the uploaded file and form elements.

Next it sets an endpoint at '/upload'. This will be the route used during development and testing. This middleware returns a basic response with file properties.

Finally, the static routes that Yeoman automatically configures are appended to the list of middleware, which is returned back to grunt-connect.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration property for adding a file upload handler to grunt-connect.

```
livereload: {
  options: {
    open: true,
    base: [ '.tmp', '<%= yeoman.app %>' ],
    middleware: function (connect, options) {
      var middlewares = [

        connect().use(connect.bodyParser({ uploadDir: '.tmp' })),
        connect().use('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
          /*
          console.log(req.files); // files properties
          console.log(req.body); // form properties
          */
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

          // response with basic file stats
          res.end(JSON.stringify({ 
            'size': req.files.file.size, 
            'path' : req.files.file.path, 
            'other' : null }));
        })
      ];

      // add the static paths in options.base
      options.base.forEach(function (base) {
        middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
      });

      return middlewares;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an error: POST http://localhost:9000/upload 405 (Method Not Allowed)